# Masquerading docker interface and host interface

Tags: linux, docker, docker-network, tun, masquerade

I am running a docker on a host and I would like to connect a specific interface inside the docker (TUN interface) to one the host's external interfaces.

When running `ifconfig` inside the docker, I see 3 interfaces: `eth0`, `lo` and `my_tun` (tun interface).
On the host, I see `lo`, `docker0` and `enp7s0` (external network).
The result I seek for, is that packets that are sent on the `my_tun` interface will be sent to the `enp7s0`.

If the TUN interface was not inside a docker, I would do something like:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

So my question is how to do it with a TUN interface that belongs to a docker container (preferably on Ubuntu).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it at last with an intermediate network.
I created a docker network of type bridge and connected it to the container and the host. Then I used iptables rules inside the container to forward communication from the tun device to the network and similar rules on the host to forward communication from the network to the external interface.

So assuming the network is named `proxy_net`, its docker interface is `proxy_net0` and its gateway is `192.168.1.254`.

Inside the container:

```sh
iptables -A FORWARD -i my_tun -o proxy_net0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i proxy_net0 -o my_tun -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o proxy_net0 -j MASQUERADE
ip route replace default via 192.168.1.254 dev proxy_net0
```

On the host:

```sh
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i proxy_net -o enp7s0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp7s0-o proxy_net -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
```